# What technology are they using to create animations

Tags: angularjs, html, flash, animation, photoshop

I am well versed with server-side programming using .Net C# and front-end MVC and Angular. I have seen some state of the art websites where they have animations included in webpages. Since it seems like Flash might be on the verge of extinction I do not want to spend time to learn it. What other technologies are they using to add animations to websites? For example to add accessories to cars with animations. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You might be talking about [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API), which is inserted into HTML5 with a **canvas** tag. It renders graphics with JavaScript but uses a web version of OpenGL.

You can simplify a lot of work with additional libraries for WebGL such as [Three.js](https://threejs.org/), p5.js and others. That way you don't have to work with shaders, and build models with individual vertices and polygons.

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was looking for.